# Unix join produces inconsistent results on Windows 7

Tags: unix, join, sed, awk

Have a data set where the max number of records in one file is ~ 130,000.

Here is a subset of the first file, 1.txt:

```
CID|UID|Key|sis_URL
1|D000108|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779
1|D000108|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622
1|D000644|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779
1|D000644|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622
1|D002331|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779
1|D002331|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622
11|C024565|WSLDOOZREJYCGB|http://sis.gov/regno=0000107062
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0000120821
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0063697187
```

Here is a subset of the second file, 2.txt:

```
CID|bro_URL
11|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0149
13|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0119
```

Am running gnuwin32 under Windows 7, 64 bit with 8gb memory; therefore need to use double quote for windows. The join command is:

```
join -t"|" -1 1 -2 1 -a1 -a2 -e "NULL" -o "0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2" 1.txt 2.txt > 3_.txt
```

Here is the output file, 3.txt.

```
CID|UID|Key|sis_URL|bro_URL
1|D000108|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779|NULL
1|D000108|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622|NULL
1|D000644|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779|NULL
1|D000644|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622|NULL
1|D002331|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779|NULL
1|D002331|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622|NULL
11|NULL|NULL|NULL|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0149
13|NULL|NULL|NULL|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0119
11|C024565|WSLDOOZREJYCGB|http://sis.gov/regno=0000107062|NULL
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0000120821|NULL
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0063697187|NULL
```

For CID:11 and CID:13, I am expecting:

```
11|C024565|WSLDOOZREJYCGB|http://sis.gov/regno=0000107062|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0149
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0000120821|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0119
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0063697187|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0119
```

Why does the `join` on CID:11 and CID:13 fail?

Note: before posting this question I ran the subset above and produced the proper results. When I run the complete set, I get the improper result (the subset shown here).

Any idea why? Any recommended alternative?

When I've completed the `join` process, my final table will be 15 columns wide. But I'm already stymied at column 4.

Any proposed work-around, such as `awk`?

Comment: Thank you - the awk script produced the proper result. Have three questions. (a) initially I ran the command with a different file order (1.txt 2.txt). That did not work. Please explain why you ordered the files 2.txt 1.txt. (b) Would you provide a bit of documentation so I can scale this approach to repeat the awk process another 10 times as I incrementally build the final result? (c) How to introduce NULL if a field in the row is blank?

Comment: You are welcome. I will have a look at this. By the way, you should give this comment below my answer, not here at your question..

Comment: When run on Unix (Mac OS X specifically), the `join` command on your data produces the answer you expect, both with and without the heading rows in the data.  However, the `join` command expects the data in the files to be sorted, and funny things can happen when the input is not sorted, and the heading rows mean the data is not sorted. One item for you to check is whether dropping the headings makes things work for you on Windows. However, it still isn't obvious how it would go wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks for advice. I do know to sort the data on the key field and had done so on the master files. But because the files are large, I could only put the subset here. The subset join works; the master join has the problem above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following command:

```
awk -f a.awk 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==FNR{
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
{
    if ($1 in a)
        $(NF+1)=a[$1]
    else 
        $(NF+1)="NULL"
    print
}
```

with output:

```
CID|UID|Key|sis_URL|bro_URL
1|D000108|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779
1|D000108|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622
1|D000644|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779
1|D000644|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622
1|D002331|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0000870779
1|D002331|RDHQFKQIGNGIED|http://sis.gov/regno=0014992622
11|C024565|WSLDOOZREJYCGB|http://sis.gov/regno=0000107062|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0149
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0000120821|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0119
13|C009947|PBKONEOXTCPAFI|http://sis.gov/regno=0063697187|http://bro.gov/nmbr=0119
```

**Explanation**

- We read the data in `2.txt` into the associative array `a`
- The test `NR==FNR` is used to match only the first file on the command line, that is the file `2.txt`
- The `next` statement is important so that the next rules are not executed for `2.txt`
- The second rule (the one containing the `if` test) is then executed only for `1.txt` but the information from `2.txt` is still available through the array `a`
- If the first field matches a field in the first column in `2.txt`, that is: `if ($1 in a)`, then we insert that value at the end of the line (`NF` is the number of fields (that is: columns) read from `1.txt`)
- If there is no match, we insert the string `"NULL"`

Comment: Thank you - the awk script produced the proper result. Have three questions. (a) initially I ran the command with a different file order (1.txt 2.txt). That did not work. Please explain why you ordered the files 2.txt 1.txt. (b) Would you provide a bit of documentation so I can scale this approach to repeat the awk process another 10 times as I incrementally build the final result? (c) How to introduce NULL if a field in the row is blank? Thank you again for a quick, effective solution. I'll mark your solution as answered.

Comment: @JayGray What do you mean by inserting NULL field? You mean at the end of each row that is not matched by a row in `1.txt`?

Comment: @JayGray The ordering of the files at the command line is important for `awk`.. It starts with the first argument (the left-most) and processes this file first.. Therefore the program will not work if you change the order..

Comment: When using unix join, I use the flag -e and then use "NULL" as a value when there is no match for the join. For example, in 3.txt join inserted NULL for CID:1 because there is no match from 2.txt. I use the -e flag to put a value in a "cell" that is otherwise blank. Hoping to use a similar feature in your awk script.

Comment: Thank you again Håkon. I now have a chance to get this work done today :->